# What to flag for "lack of basic research" questions?

Tags: support, questions, close-reasons, content-level, quality

There have been a variety of questions that shouldn't be allowed under current site rules because they are very clearly lacking basic research - 2 minutes on google would probably help them with their question. It seems clear to me that they should be closed, but I am not sure for which reason to flag, I've had a few flags declined recently for incorrect use and wish to avoid this in the future

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closing "Insufficient Effort" questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6001/)

Comment: also [Questions that show insufficient effort by the OP](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4598/) and [What does everyone mean by “insufficient research effort”?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8789/)